# Write to remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn about how programs and apps communicate with servers. I have Ubuntu server set up with MySQL server. I have adjusted the bind-address and port 3306 with ufw allow. When I run a python program on a different machine to update the MySQL database I get an interface 2003 and 10060 error for no communication response. I am new to this sort of thing I have intermediate experience with programming and I am having trouble finding answers. I am 99% sure I missed something small or just did something stupid or possibly didn’t do something. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you open your firewall so the comms can happen on 3306

Comment: Does the user account you are using to connect  have the priv to connect remotely

Comment: I used ufw allow port 3306. I even used iptables to make sure port 3306 was open. I set up user and granted all privileges and flushed them. I know it is something small and/or stupid that is causing this problem

Comment: do you have set bind-address to *.*.*.* ?

Comment: I have bind-address set to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to programming?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why when I run a program to write to a remote mysql database I get absolutely no response from server. I get a 10060 time out error

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

You can check connectivity with that command on client machine (python) :

```
nc -vz -w5 IP_MYSQL_SERVER 3306
```

Change IP_MYSQL_SERVER  with the IP of your ubuntu server that run mysql server.

If that OK you can install mysql client on client machine and try a full mysql connection

```
mysql -h IP_MYSQL_SERVER  -u USER -p
```

Comment: Client machine is a laptop with windows and the program language is python. Server side is Ubuntu server with Apache and MySQL server

Comment: the myslq command works in windows terminal if mysql client exec is in the path